# Pi addressing ping to the wrong destination

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, dns

I have a private network that requires end to end connectivity

pi 1 -> device 1 -> device 2 -> pi 2

The traffic is getting all the way from pi 1 to pi 2

However, the return doesn't work

Examining the ip packets, pi 2 is setting a dns server as it's destination:

```
 tfIpIncomingPacket:eth0:IN:tag=0x1129: 192.168.69.101/34373 -> 8.8.8.8/53 UDP id=40849 len=67 tos=0x00 flags=0x4000 ttl=64
```

(source is 192.168.69.101, destination is 8.8.8.8)

The destination should be 192.168.68.1. Any ideas why it's trying to address this to a DNS server?

Here's the network config for pi2 for reference:

```
interface eth0
metric 0
inform 192.168.69.101
static routers=192.168.69.100
```

Comment: how are you routing traffic between 192.168.69.x and 192.168.68.x? or are you using something like a /23 (or lower) subnet?

Comment: Welcome.  Please edit in the output of `ip r` from both pis (and other intermediate devices if possible).  You say 'ping' in the title; you should clarify whether you mean a normal icmp ping sent with `ping`, or else explain exactly what you are sending and how.  I mention this because the incoming packet in your example is not an ICMP ping or response, **it's a UDP packet, addressed to a DNS server port** (53), as mentioned in the answer by Ljm, so it is probably correctly addressed (to DNS server).

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that the DNS-package that you gave in the question is the reply packet from something coming from Pi1.

There is too little information in the question to tell you where the problem is. So we resort to some general fault-seeking.

I assume the following:

- Pi1 is 192.168.68.1, since you suggest that this would need to be the destination of the packets.
- Pi2 is 192.168.69.101
- the intermediate device are some sort of routers
- networks are /24
- network between device1 and device2 is  192.168.A.0/24, with A not 69 or 69.
- device1 has IP 192.168.68.d1 (with d1 not equal to 1, because that is where pi lives) and 192.168.A.d1 on the other side
- device2 has IP 192.168.A.d2 on one side (d1 not equal to d2), and 192.168.69.100 on the other side.
- icmp echo is not filtered (ping is allowed), and all device respond to pings

If these conditions are not met, make sure you understand the consequences.

Start from Pi1:

- ping 192.168.68.d1
- ping 192.168.A.d1
- ping 192.168.A.d2
- ping 192.168.69.101

From pi2:

- ping 192.168.69.100
- ping 192.168.A.d2
- ping 192.168.A.d1
- ping 192.168.68.1

You should now know which part of the connection is not working. That may be between device1 and device2.